# SQL Server Row_Count with Reset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have 6 columns:

```
Date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency, Reset Flag (0 Yes, 1 No)
```

I want to row count over partition by but reset the row count whenever a 0 appears in `Reset Flag` column. The first 5 columns are not unique but their combination forms a unique set of columns.

Please help me with this !

Every other solution I've researched doesn't work for some reason :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands style problem. Without any sample data or desired results...

Using two [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to identify groups by reset flag, and another in the outer query to number the rows by `ResetFlag` and the `grp` created in the inner query.

Change the order of `date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency` to whichever order of those columns you want to number the rows by; keep them in the same order for each of the three `row_number()`s.

```
/* ----- */ 
select 
    date
  , Account
  , Side
  , Symbol
  , Currency
  , ResetFlag
  , rn = case when ResetFlag = 0 then 0
         else row_number() over (
            partition by ResetFlag, grp
            order by date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency)
         end
from (
  select *
    , grp = row_number() over (order by date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency) 
          - row_number() over (
              partition by ResetFlag 
              order by date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency)
  from t
  ) s
order by date, Account, Side, Symbol, Currency
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VLCO32635

returns:

```
+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+----+
|    date    | Account | Side | Symbol | Currency | ResetFlag | rn |
+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 |       7 |    2 |      3 | 7,0000   |         1 |  1 |
| 2017-01-02 |       8 |    9 |      9 | 6,0000   |         1 |  2 |
| 2017-01-03 |       4 |    1 |      5 | 6,0000   |         1 |  3 |
| 2017-01-04 |       5 |    4 |      8 | 5,0000   |         0 |  0 |
| 2017-01-05 |       2 |    1 |      3 | 1,0000   |         1 |  1 |
| 2017-01-06 |       8 |    0 |      2 | 0,0000   |         0 |  0 |
| 2017-01-07 |       0 |    3 |      8 | 9,0000   |         1 |  1 |
| 2017-01-08 |       0 |    3 |      1 | 3,0000   |         1 |  2 |
+------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works though if you can explain to me what grp is doing that would be very helpful

Comment: @NewbieCoder `grp` is a unique number for each logical group that is calculated using two running numbers (`row_number()`). Both share the same `order by`, but with different partitions (in this case, one without a partition and one with a partition). This might make things a bit clearer: http://rextester.com/KFJHA53489